# Location of barchart labels in Python

Tags: python, charts

I am constructing a bar chart with labels Low Resistance, Medium Resistance and High Resistance. How can I get Python to always print the labels on the bottom right of the chart? If they are printed at the top they obscure the data.

```
axarr[0].bar(ind, y1, width, color='blue', bottom=y3)

axarr[0].bar(ind, y2, width, color='orange')

axarr[0].bar(ind, y3, width, color='green')

axarr[0].set_title('Growth in Resistance')

axarr[0].legend(('Low Resistance', 'Medium Resistance', 'High Resistance'))
```

Thanks in advance. Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
axarr[0].legend(('Low Resistance', 'Medium Resistance', 'High Resistance'), loc=4)
```

Here are possible legend locations, names that you can use or just numbers:

- ‘best’   0
- ‘upper right’    1
- ‘upper left’    2
- ‘lower left’ 3
- ‘lower  right’  4
- ‘right’ 5
- ‘center left’   6
- ‘center right’  7
- ‘lower center’  8
- ‘upper center’  9
- ‘center’    10

`loc` parameter will change the location of legend, for more info have a look here: [Matplotlib legend](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend)